# Vagrant box - rlerdorf/php7dev - start new project

Tags: vagrant

I've got `rlerdorf/php7dev` Vagrant box installed and running. I can see `phpinfo` page in browser.

How do I start new project now? I mean: what is the folder on my PC, where I can put my project/PHP files so that they are accessible via browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared folder needs setting up in `php7dev.yaml`:

```
folders:
    - map: absolute\path\to\local\folder
      to: /var/www/
```